# Keep HTML formatting when passing variable from Django template to view

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a contact form in my Django app.

In my template there is a textarea field:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="email_body" name="email_body" placeholder="Email body"></textarea>
```

In my `views.py` the content of this textarea is passed to a function that sends emails:

```
def index(request):
    # some code here
    email_body = request.POST.get('email_body')
    send_emails(email_subject, email_body, email_list) # the other variables are declared above
    # more code here
```

I don't know if it is needed, but the code for the `send_emails` function is:

```
def send_emails(email_subject, email_body, email_list):
    subject = email_subject
    message = email_body

    email = EmailMessage(subject, message, os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER'], email_list)
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.send()
```

The problem is that the email body has no text formatting. All the newline characters (from the textarea) are lost and the message is printed in a single line.

Is there a way to keep the original HTML formatting of the textarea message, when this is passed to the view and the `send_emails` function?

Comment: You need to use **safe** template tag. Read further from here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the textarea *doesn't* contain any "HTML formatting". As you say, it contains newlines; but HTML ignores those. You need to convert them into HTML break tags.

You can use the `linebreaks` template filter for this; outside of a template, it is accessible as `django.utils.html.linebreaks`.

Comment: Daniel,You are much knowledgeable,but I think you simply are mistaken at this point. The value saved by text area in DB contains proper HTML formatting tags such as bold,italic and underline with font details.One need to use safe template tag for that variable to be displayed as entered in textarea. Am I wrong ?

Comment: That would be the case if the OP was using some kind of WYSIWYG widget; however there's no indication of that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate your form/textarea using [Django's Form API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django), you could apply template tag filters such as **{{ textarea | linebreaks }}** to get the HTML formatting you require.